# How to implement the below query using ssis

Tags: ssis, etl, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, ssis-2005

Can we discuss how to load the below query result into  a destination table ,using ssis.I know we can use this in T-sql and also as an OLEDB source query.But still wondering how to implement it ,only using data flow components

```
SELECT
     CLIENTID       = CAST(PER.CLIENTID AS INT)
    ,CASEID         = CAST(CS.CASEID AS INT)
    ,CAST(RIGHT(ev.oid, 10) as int) AS EventID
    ,ev.ServiceSubtypeCode
    ,ev.ServiceSubtypeCode  +' - '+ev.ServiceSubTypeDesc as ServiceSubTypeDesc
    ,WU.ProviderID as WorkunitProviderID
    ,WU.ProviderName as WorkUnitProviderName
    ,ev.eventstartdate as AssessmentStartDate
    ,CONVERT(CHAR(5),ASM.getstarttimestamp,8) as AssessmentStartTime
    ,ev.EVENTENDDATE as AssessmentEndDate
    ,ev.EVENTENDTIME as AssessmentEndTime
    ,CAST(asm.getAssmtTemplateName as nvarchar(200)) as AssessmentTypeDesc
    ,j.providerid
    ,j.ProviderName
    ,j.ProviderRole
    ,EV.ISCOMPLETED
    , EV.ISFINALISED 
    ,EV.ISREVOKED
    , EV.REVOKEDDATE AS REVOKEDDATE
    ,ASM.OID AS ASSESSMENTID

FROM DBO.ASSESSMENT ASM
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.INDIVIDUALPERSON PER        ON ASM.MYPERSON = PER.OID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.[CASE] CS       ON ASM.MYCASE = CS.OID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                        SELECT CAST(ST.CODE AS VARCHAR(8))AS SERVICETYPECODE
                                , CAST(ST.DESCRIPTION AS VARCHAR(100)) AS SERVICETYPEDESC
                                , CAST(SST.CODE AS VARCHAR(8)) AS SERVICESUBTYPECODE
                                , CAST(SST.DESCRIPTION AS VARCHAR(100)) AS SERVICESUBTYPEDESC
                                , DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD,0,EV.GETRPSSTARTTIMESTAMP)) AS EVENTSTARTDATE
                                , CONVERT(CHAR(5),EV.GETRPSSTARTTIMESTAMP,8) AS EVENTSTARTTIME
                                , DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD,0,EV.GETRPSENDTIMESTAMP)) AS EVENTENDDATE
                                , CONVERT(CHAR(5),EV.GETRPSENDTIMESTAMP,8) AS EVENTENDTIME
                                ,CAST(VEN.DESCRIPTION AS VARCHAR(12)) AS EVENTVENUE
                                ,EV.ISCOMPLETED
                                , EV.ISFINALISED 
                                ,EV.ISREVOKED
                                , DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD,0,EV.REVOKEDON)) AS REVOKEDDATE 
                                , EV.OID 
                                        from Event ev
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN     ServiceType AS st ON ev.myServiceType = st.oid 
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN  ServiceSubtype AS sst ON ev.myServiceSubtype = sst.oid
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN  AllCodes AS ven ON ev.myEventVenueCode = ven.oid 
                                     )as  EV
ON ASM.MYEVENT = EV.OID
LEFT OUTER JOIN     (
                                        select wu.oid
                                        ,CAST(wu.providerid AS VARCHAR(100)) AS providerid
                                        ,CAST(nm.getfullname AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ProviderName
                                        ,wu.contactname
                                        ,wu.activatedate as StartDate
                                        ,wu.deactivatedate as EndDate
                                        ,case when wu.deactivatedate is null then 1 else 0 end as IsActiveToday
                                        from workunitprovider wu
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.allprovidernames nm    ON wu.oid = nm.myprovider
                                        where nm.myNameType in (02245.0000000252)
                                    ) as WU
ON ASM.MYWORKUNITPROVIDER = WU.OID
Left join   (                   
                                select f.myEvent
                                ,f.myProvider
                                ,f.myproviderrolecode
                                ,f.Max_ProvOid
                                ,CAST(g.providerid AS VARCHAR(100)) AS providerid
                                ,CAST( i.description AS VARCHAR(150)) AS ProviderRole
                                ,cast (h.getFullName as nvarchar (150)) as ProviderName
                                    from(           select d.myEvent
                                                        ,myProvider
                                                        ,myproviderrolecode
                                                        ,d.Max_ProvOid
                                                         from (                 select  A.myEvent, max(b.oid) as Max_ProvOid
                                                                                    from alleventitems a
                                                                                    left outer join ProviderEventItemRole as b  on a.oid = b.myeventitem
                                                                                    group by A.myEvent
                                                                        ) as d
                                                                        left join 
                                                                        (                           select  A.myEvent,b.myProvider,b.myproviderrolecode,a.oid as a_oid,b.oid as b_oid
                                                                                                    from alleventitems a
                                                                                                    left outer join ProviderEventItemRole as b  on a.oid = b.myeventitem
                                                                        )as e on d.myevent = e.myevent and max_provOid = b_oid
                                ) as f
                                left join dbo.allproviders as g on f.myProvider = g.oid
                                left join (
                                                    select * 
                                                    from dbo.AllProviderNames 
                                                    where mynametype ='02245.0000000252'
                                                )as h on f.myprovider =h.myprovider
                                left join dbo.allcodes as i on f.myproviderrolecode = i.oid 
    )as j on ASM.myevent = j.myevent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we begin, a disclaimer:

*Complex SELECT queries are best expressed in T-SQL.  SSIS is best used for ETL tasks.*

Now... with that out of the way.  Let's see what we have.  That query has fifteen `LEFT JOINS` nested across three levels: Five at the top, seven at the middle, and two at the bottom.   Peppered throughout are a some `CAST()`s  and `GROUP BY`s.   All of those SQL commands can be done with SSIS components.

- JOIN = Merge Join component.
- GROUP BY = Aggregate component.
- CAST =  Derived Column component.

Since you have such a large query, I'd recommend breaking this into smaller chunks.  Starting with the inner most join.

```
    select 
        d.myEvent
        ,myProvider
        ,myproviderrolecode
        ,d.Max_ProvOid
    from (                 
        select  A.myEvent, max(b.oid) as Max_ProvOid
        from alleventitems a
        left outer join ProviderEventItemRole as b  
        on a.oid = b.myeventitem
        group by A.myEvent
    ) as d
    left join (                           
        select  A.myEvent,b.myProvider,b.myproviderrolecode,a.oid as a_oid,b.oid as b_oid
        from alleventitems a
        left outer join ProviderEventItemRole as b  
        on a.oid = b.myeventitem
    ) as e
```

Translating that to SSIS would look like this.

[image]

Above, we're merging four tables into one.  You can learn more about how to configure Merge Joins [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-merge-join-transformation/).   Repeat the above pattern for the remaining JOINS and connect them all together and you will have translated the entire query to SSIS!

---

Now that we can see *how* it may  be done, may I ask why we'd want to do this in SSIS?

Comment: ... and if you insist on it being done, please oh please post record counts and comparative performance!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.If I can do it using ssis then it is going to be fast!?

Comment: do not we need to aggregate the column before the join!? ,in this situvation

Comment: @user1254579 Yes, Aggregate BEFORE the Merge Join, good catch!  No, I don't think it will be faster than T-SQL, but might as well try and see.  To help, keep in mind that  SORTING must happen on every Merge Join key column.  That will hurt performance, so - as I did above - I recommend having having an ORDER BY clause in your Source queries and then setting the IsSorted property to not incur additional sort costs.